# create a Jekyll GitHub blog as a subdirectory of an Organization

Tags: github, io, jekyll, blogs

I want to know if creating a Jekyll GitHub blog for a particular GitHub page will associate itself with that entire GitHub entity or if it is possible to make multiple Jekyll blogs under the auspices of a single GitHub profile.

I'm part of an "Organization" on GitHub, my research group, and I want to create a blog for a particulat project following [this tutorial](http://jekyllbootstrap.com/usage/jekyll-quick-start.html), i.e. "Jekyll QuickStart: Host on GitHub in 3 Minutes".

At first I created an entirely new and seperate GitHub profile from which to host this blog, but it would be better if I could create this blog as a repository within the Organization to which I belong since most the people that need to access this blog are already associated with that organization.

But it would be suboptimal if this one blog were the only things that could be associated with the organization since the organization is involved in things other than this project as well.

So for these GitHub blogs is it 1 page/organization = 1 blog, or can we have a one to many mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already got a Github Pages repository set up for the organization (e.g. `some-org.github.io`), then any additional `gh-pages` repository will be accessible via `some-org.github.io/<repo name>`.

For example, I've got the organization "SusHack", and it has a repository called `sushack.github.io`.

`sushack.github.io` serves the main domain of `sushack.co.uk`, and we've got a project repository under that organization with a `gh-pages` branch, e.g. `https://github.com/sushack/PuppetMaster/tree/gh-pages`, and it is accessible via `sushack.github.io/PuppetMaster` or `sushack.co.uk/PuppetMaster`

So to recap:

1. Make a `<orgname>.github.io` repository under the Organization. In this you can create a file called `CNAME` to define a custom domain, or just use `<orgname>.github.io`.
2. Make a repository called `blog` with a `gh-pages` branch. You can push your Jekyll codebase to this branch, and Github will build it for you
3. Access your blog via `<orgname>.github.io/blog/`.

Comment: I think you can redact your answer. In the user/organization branch, the Github Pages branch is `master`. See https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages/#user--organization-pages